# Invalid field for SObject Account

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, dynamic-apex

Im trying to get editable fields and non editable fields and use them to iterate in visualforce using apex:repeat.

Apex:code

```
readOnlyFields   = new List<SObjectField>();
    accessableFields = new List<SObjectField>();
    for(SObjectField field :sObjectType.Account.fields.getMap().values()){
        if(field.getDescribe().isAccessible() && !field.getDescribe().isUpdateable() && !field.getDescribe().isCreateable()){
            readOnlyFields.add(field);
            nonEditableFields +=field + ',';
        }else{
            accessableFields.add(field);
            editableFields +=field + ',';
        }
    }
```

Vf Code:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!accessableFields}" var="a">
<tr><td>{!selectedList1.[a]}</td></tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

selectedList1 is an account type which contains account information.

can some one hep me to  avoid this error.
Error: Invalid field  for SObject Account

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
List<String> accessableFields = new List<String>();
String nonEditableFields = '';
String editableFields = '';

for(SObjectField field :SObjectType.Account.fields.getMap().values()){
    if(field.getDescribe().isAccessible() && !field.getDescribe().isUpdateable() && !field.getDescribe().isCreateable()){
        readOnlyFields.add(field.getDescribe().name);
        nonEditableFields += field.getDescribe().name + ',';
    }else{
        accessableFields.add(field.getDescribe().name);
        editableFields += field.getDescribe().name + ',';
    }
}

System.debug(readOnlyFields);
System.debug(accessableFields);
System.debug(nonEditableFields);
System.debug(editableFields);
```

Bascically returning `List<String>` instead of `List<SObjectField>`?

Comment: Now im trying to display list of accessible feilds using apex:repeat

<apex:repeat value="{!accessableFields}" var="a">
                    <tr><td>{!selectedList1[a]}</td></tr>
                </apex:repeat>

Im facing an error : Incorrect parameter type for subscript. Expected Text, received FieldToken

Comment: Hi @Ram I was misled (should have re-read). I was primarily looking at the way you tried to create the `nonEditableFields` and `editableFields` strings. But indeed in order to dynamically bind within the VF page you need to have `readOnlyFields` and `accessibleFields` as a `List<SObjectField>`. Can you try to use:

`<td><td><apex:outputField value="{!selectedList1[a]}"/></td></tr>`